# Route between lazy loaded modules ion angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have 2 lazy loaded modules declared in my AppModule:

```
 {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboards/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
},
{
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
```

The auth module contains the login page. On successful login, it should redirect to the dashboard. Sadly, I cannot manage to navigate to the dashboard out of the auth module. I tried

```
 this.router.navigate([ 'dashboard' ]);
 this.router.navigate([ './dashboard' ]);
 this.router.navigate([ '../dashboard' ]);
```

Auth Module Routes:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthContainerComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'login',
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
        }, ...]}
```

Dashboard Module Routes:

```
  {
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customer/customer.module').then(m => m.CustomerModule),
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    data: {
        roles: [ Roles.Customer ]
    },
},
{
    path: 'staff',
    loadChildren: () => import('./staff/staff.module').then(m => m.StaffModule),
},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'customer', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Any ideas why it is not working? Is it because the modules are lazy loaded? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: can you post the routing definition of the dashboard.module  ?

Comment: @AkhilChandran no, i subscribed to the router events and when i call navigate it always results in '/auth/login'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, totally my bad. The Auth Guard was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboards/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
},
```

Please remove this until problem is clear:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

It should be possible to navigate to

```
this.router.navigate([ 'dashboard/customer' ]);
this.router.navigate([ 'dashboard/staff' ]);
```

but only if these modules (staff and customer) have a path:'' in its mapping config.

Can you publish the code of CustomerModule and StaffModule? A stackblitz would be perfect ;-)

You can also activate logging for routing in your app router with:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}),
```